How do I insert schema.org metadata for all the images in a views-generated page?
I've got many pages containing image galleries generated by views with context filters. I would like to insert the schema.org metadata into the page containing metadata (licensing etc) for each image on the page. Is there any contrib module allowing to do that? I looked at the Schema.org Metadata module but I can't see how I could set up metadata for multiple images which are not a fixed part of the content item but are picked up by a view. Maybe I was not looking hard enough?
I guess I could include another view on the same page with the same filters but different markup for the metadata but how do I put the results into the header where the schema.org metadata is supposed to go? Or maybe it's OK to include it in the body?
